# Mysql ругается на concat

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT u.id,u.email,u.dateCreated,DATE(NOW()) as date_now,c.name,
CASE c.name WHEN "M2M" THEN 'MONTH' ELSE "YEAR" END as type_value
FROM users u
JOIN contract_type c
ON u.contract_type = c.id
HAVING date_now > u.dateCreated + INTERVAL CONCAT("1",type_value)
```

Ругается на Concat,где ошибку допустил скажите

Answer (score 1):

После слова **INTERVAL** и числа должно быть ключевое слово ( day, month, year ) а не переменная или выражение.

Попробуйте так:

```
HAVING date_now >  CASE type_value
       WHEN "YEAR" THEN date_add(u.dateCreated, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
       WHEN "MONTH" THEN date_add(u.dateCreated, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
       END
```